# Flutter: how to fix stutter when opening camera

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that allows the user to take pictures in several places.
Now that the functionalities are finalized, I wanted to started optimizing the app's performance aspect. Running Flutter Performance made me realize it runs with frametimes within 16ms most of the time, with the notable exception of the moments the camera opens to let the user take their picture.

The way I open the camera simply uses the `ImagePicker` package like this:

```
final XFile? file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      preferredCameraDevice:
      isSelfie ? CameraDevice.front : CameraDevice.rear,);
    return file == null ? null : File(file.path);
```

So I'm looking for a way to maybe optimize this as to get consistently good performance.

I also get worse performance when scrolling a `SingleChildScrollView` with busy items that display images and buttons, if you have a suggestion to make the performance better, I'll take it !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

here a few tips:
Make sure you run app via profile/release mode for checking Performance

If you profile with iOS and are using Flutter under 3.10 (which use impeller as default) check for `Shader Jank` [Flutter doc about Shader Jank](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/shader)

For `SingleChildScrollView`, the content of `SingleChildScrollView` will always been drawn even if the item not in the viewport (visible for user), consider change to using `ListView` which will render the part that visible user only